# airflow cluster cant't fetch logs from workers

Tags: docker, airflow, celery

The airflow cluster accesses the worker log error, and accesses  the worker in the master node will not report an error.I can't solve my proplem.I used the docker develoment my airflow and celery.can you help me?Thanks!!!

```
*** Log file does not exist: /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=example_bash_operator/run_id=scheduled__2022-09-23T00:00:00+00:00/task_id=runme_1/attempt=1.log
*** Fetching from: http://eosbak01.zzz.ac.cn:8793/log/dag_id=example_bash_operator/run_id=scheduled__2022-09-23T00:00:00+00:00/task_id=runme_1/attempt=1.log
*** !!!! Please make sure that all your Airflow components (e.g. schedulers, webservers and workers) have the same 'secret_key' configured in 'webserver' section and time is synchronized on all your machines (for example with ntpd) !!!!!
****** See more at https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#secret-key
****** Failed to fetch log file from worker. Client error '403 FORBIDDEN' for url 'http://eosbak01.zzz.ac.cn:8793/log/dag_id=example_bash_operator/run_id=scheduled__2022-09-23T00:00:00+00:00/task_id=runme_1/attempt=1.log'
For more information check: https://httpstatuses.com/403
```

#### WorkerNode

```
[airflow@eosbak01 deploy]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                        PORTS      NAMES
2ef39a54de97   apache/airflow:2.3.4   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute (healthy)   8080/tcp   deploy_airflow-worker_
```

#### MainNode

```
[airflow@eosbak02 deploy]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                                                  NAMES
1e6a7e50831d   apache/airflow:2.3.4   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:5555->5555/tcp, :::5555->5555/tcp, 8080/tcp    deploy_flower_1
9afb5985b9f3   apache/airflow:2.3.4   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   27 minutes ago   Up 27 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp              deploy_airflow-webserver_1
80132177ae3d   apache/airflow:2.3.4   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   27 minutes ago   Up 27 minutes (healthy)   8080/tcp                                               deploy_airflow-triggerer_1
6ea5a0ed7dec   apache/airflow:2.3.4   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   27 minutes ago   Up 27 minutes (healthy)   8080/tcp                                               deploy_airflow-scheduler_1
2787acb189ad   mysql:8.0.27           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   29 minutes ago   Up 29 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, :::3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   deploy_mysql_1
057af26f6070   redis:latest           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   29 minutes ago   Up 29 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp, :::6379->6379/tcp              deploy_redis_1
```

Comment: If not mistaken https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/26493 will fix this issue. airflow 2.4.1 rc1 is expected this week